# Executing two commands on the same page with exec()

Tags: php, node.js

I am using the following code to try and execute two different commands from button clicks in a php webpage.

```
    <?php

 if (isset($_POST['button'])) { exec('/usr/local/bin/node desktop/server.js'); } ?>
<form method="POST">
<p>
<input type="hidden" name="button" value="1">
<input type="submit" value="Start Video">
</p>
</form>

    <?php

 if (isset($_POST['button'])) { exec('/usr/local/bin/node desktop/test.js'); }   ?>
<form method="POST">
<p>
<input type="hidden" name="button" value="1">
<input type="submit" value="Test">
</p>
</form>
```

I can get the first command to execute ok to start the server and it works fine but when I then click on the second one nothing happens. I have tried each of them just on the webpage individually and they both work fine on their own but what i want to do is start the server then run the other script, but it won't allow me for some reason?

Comment: I assume your code shows two different files?

Answer (score 1):

Please note that nodejs applications normally don't stop. And that exec will wait for the end of the called program. The combination of both will freeze PHP until the nodejs process has finished. Depending on your web server, there can be more or fewer simultaneous PHP processes or threads, but normally this number is limited, so you should avoid this situation. And there is another reason to avoid this situation: Your browser will trying to load the page forever (until timeout) because it never receives the end of the page.

You can simply avoid this problem, if you append an ampersand to the end of the command line:

```
exec('/usr/local/bin/node desktop/server.js &');
```

This will make the nodejs progress starting in background, and your PHP script can continue.

Comment: Also, if there's no need for the node script to keep running, you can add process.exit() to the end of it.

Comment: @MattBrowne Yes and no. The name `server.js` tells me that it will wait (at least some time) and wait for incoming connections...

Comment: Hi, thanks for that, where would I put in process.exit()? After the if statement?

Comment: Is there a way to stop the server.js script after a certain amount of time?

Comment: @matt I was referring to your node.is code, not your PHP code. Why are you creating a form to start a node.js server in the first place?

Comment: @matt Try to use the `timeout` linux command. But normally you shouldn't start any servers from PHP anyway. This is always a hack, mostly used for testing, on hosted servers for bypassing restrictions or on embedded devices